# QT QML Mouse Pointer Rotation

Tags: qml, mouse-cursor

My application is running on QML-Qt5 on an embedded linux device.
The mouse pointer appears when i plug it in the USB port, but when i rotate my application to 180° the mouse pointer and its coordinates dont rotate.
Here is my app:

```
Item
{

    id: base
    signal handlerLoader(string name)
    property int click:1
    width:1280
    height: 800

    property int rotation_dialog:0

    Rectangle
    {
        id: view
        color: "#000000"
        width: base.width
        height: base.height
    .....
```

When my display rotates i go and rotate the view rectangle like "view.rotation:180"
Everything inside will rotate but not the mouse cursor.
Is there a way to rotate the mouse cursor too?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known bug in Qt](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-39959) (I ran into the same problem). Supposedly fixed in Qt 5.8.

Comment: It still doenst work on Qt5.9.1, the mouse doenst rotate. You can set the enviroment variable to rotate the mouse pointer to 180 degrees but the clicks event still thinks it is at 0°.